# How to determine whether java class is anonymous?

Tags: java, class, code-analysis, anonymous-class

I have such code:

```
package x.y.z;

public class Test
{
    private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("World");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        };

        final Runnable r2 = new MyRunnable();

        r1.run();
        r2.run();
    }
}
```

I am working on some code analysis module, and I want to prove that `r1` is  an anonymous class instance and `r2` is not. Both of them are valid objects having the same base class or an interface. How can I do this?

**Refinement**: All classes are being loaded, so I do not need to analyze the text.

Comment: You may check that the call to the constructor is followed by whitespaces and `{` ?

Comment: @Berger there might be newlines as well :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the [`isAnonymousClass` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAnonymousClass--) on `Class`, so:

```
if (r1.getClass().isAnonymousClass()) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Yes, I must have missed such a simple way ... Thanks a lot.